# How to ensure Xamarin.ios extension project deploys with main project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-extensions

I am trying to add inward sharing to an existing Xamarin.iOS project in Visual Studio.  I have added a share extension project (using the template project in VS), however when I test on the device nothing shows in the OS sharing screen.  I've built and tested a [MS sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios8-share/) which works fine and does show on the device.
I think the problem is that the second EXE for my app isn't being deployed at all when I test.  When I press F5 to run the MS project on an attached device, the Build Output window includes lines such as:

```
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 40%
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension.aotdata.arm64
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension.aotdata.arm64
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 41%
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension.dll
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 41%
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension.dll
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 41%
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension.dll
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 42%
CopyingFile - Path: /var/folders/ns/vw2n_fhd58d3v21nv64s4fhw0000gn/T/Xamarin.iOS_InstallShadowPath/Share.app.mXLJ6c/Share.app_sparse.ipa/Payload/Share.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex/libmono-native-compat.dylib
```

It is clearly copying the second project to the /plugins/ sub-folder.  However when I press F5 for my own app there are numerous lines in the build output for my main project and its resources etc, but no such equivalent for the second project, or any reference to a plugins sub-folder.
In my app's solution I have set the extension project to build (and the deployment tick box is not available for xamarin.ios in the configuration manager).  In the solution properties I've set my main project as dependent on the second project.  I have verified that the second project does build: if I introduce an error, or change its ID such that the bundle ID no longer matches my wildcarded provisioning profile then the build and deploy terminates with an error.

How do I ensure that the extension project is included (both when testing the solution from VS and when building an IPA for upload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the share extension from the main project to ensure that it is included in the built binary.

However, that won't grant that the app will appear while you share, you need to specify what your app receives in the `info.plist` file of your share extension.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it probably is it.  I can't verify it successfully deploys as with the reference it now fails with a cryptic "ditto exited with code 0", but it does seem to be attempting it.